# Why does sendmail work differently in different shells?

Tags: bash, shell, solaris, ksh, sendmail

The following code works when I directly run it in `bash` shell:

```
SUBJECT="SUBJECT-"`date`;
MAIL_FROM="abc@site.com";
MAIL_TO="abc@site.com";
MAIL_CC="abc@site.com";
MAIL_FILE="/path/of/html/body.html";
(echo -e "Subject: $SUBJECT\nMIME-Version: 1.0\nFrom: $MAIL_FROM\nTo:$MAIL_TO\nCc:$MAIL_CC\nContent-Type: text/html\nContent-Disposition: inline\n\n";/bin/cat $MAIL_FILE) | /usr/sbin/sendmail -f  $MAIL_FROM $MAIL_TO;
```

But when I try to run it within a script like below...

Contents of mail.sh:

```
#!/usr/bin/ksh

SUBJECT="SUBJECT-"`date`;
MAIL_FROM="abc@site.com";
MAIL_TO="abc@site.com";
MAIL_CC="abc@site.com";
MAIL_FILE="/path/of/html/body.html";
(echo -e "Subject: $SUBJECT\nMIME-Version: 1.0\nFrom: $MAIL_FROM\nTo:$MAIL_TO\nCc:$MAIL_CC\nContent-Type: text/html\nContent-Disposition: inline\n\n";/bin/cat $MAIL_FILE) | /usr/sbin/sendmail -f  $MAIL_FROM $MAIL_TO;
```

I get the following results...

`$ sh mail.sh  #Mail sent but the body is in text format containing "-e Subject: SUBJECT-Wed Jan 30 04:45:42 EST....."` and the HTML code rendered as text.

`$ bash mail.sh  # Mail is received with mail body containing correct HTML format.`

So it seems that `echo -e` is recognized by bash. But when I use "#!/usr/bin/bash" and run the script as `$ sh mail.sh` I still get a mail in text format.

Why is this so..? *Thanks in advance for your suggestions.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Solaris `echo`

```
$ echo -e foo
-e foo
```

does not work like <strike>most</strike> some other `echo` commands:

```
$ bash
$ echo -e foo
foo 
$ which echo
/usr/bin/echo
$ type -t echo
builtin
```

The `bash` builtin version works as expected, the `ksh` builtin keeps the Solaris behaviour (`echo` behaviour is usually system dependent in `ksh` when options are used).
A plain `echo` should work in `ksh`, no `-e`:

```
$ ksh
$ echo -e "foo\nbar"
-e foo
bar
$ echo "foo\nbar"
foo
bar
```

So you have a *Solaris* problem, rather than a *sendmail* problem :-)

You could try `printf` as a more portable way of doing this.

Comment: Okay.. Wow it would have taken me a while to figure that out. Will try it with `printf` instead. Thanks!

Comment: The `-e` is a GNU extension.

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/65803/5132 is relevant here.